# Enabling nyc / istanbul code coverage for files outside the package directory

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, istanbul, nyc

I have a node application with separate sister folders and accompanying package.json files for the application code and tests.

```
Project
|
|-----Application
          |-----app.js
          |-----package.json
|-----Tests
        |
        |-------test.js
        |-------package.json  (nyc added here)
```

nyc is included as a dependency(along with mocha) in the test folder. 
It fails to show coverage for files in the application folder.
I have tried to explicitly include application files by including "../Application/**/*.js"
in the nyc config, bit that does not seem to do the trick.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

I found out that you can do this by using an obscure option called cwd as follows:

```
  "nyc": {
    "all": true,
    "check-coverage": true,
    "per-file": true,
    "lines": 99,
    "statements": 99,
    "functions": 99,
    "branches": 99,
    **"cwd" : "../",**
    "exclude" : [
      "Tests/**/*.js"
    ]
  }
```